# Codeigniter 3 404 page not found after hosting but working properly in localhost

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, routes, http-status-code-404

my website is not opening when I write `greenvaleschool.in` but only opens when I write `greenvaleschool.in/home` In codeigniter 3. The routes.php is not working. It works only when I provide controller name and method name. example `greenvaleschool.in/home/gallery`.
I host it from godaddy web hosting

File route

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'Home';
```

I adjusted all the case sensitives. used the following in my .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

dear user their might be some issue may be you are adding the project in subfolder then use the **RewriteBase** else no need and also if in sub folder then folder path

```
RewriteEngine On
#optional for sub directory
RewriteBase /directory/
#above line
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

cross check your route is use set the default controller to home then it will call the index method of the controller else you need to define the method name to call on base_url one more thing you don't need to write the controller name in capitalize way
for home controller index method

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home';
```

or

```
$route['default_controller'] = 'home/index';
$route['default_controller'] = 'controller_name/method_name';
```